# Google play organization Developer verification

Tags: identity, google-play-console, service-accounts, google-developers-console, submit-button

Hi I'm trying to verify my organization developer account on google play console, I have all the necessary  documents but after filling the forms and uploading all the document, the submit button is not working thou it not disabled, any time I go back to check if I did something wrong whiles filling the form, where i'm supposed to choose City is highlighted in red while I have entered the the city. I have cleared my cache an[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2FTE.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKbgG.png) switch Browsers but still please help.

I have tried switching browsers, clearing my cache, all I was expecting is to submit the document for review  so that my account can be verified